# Bug animation Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, animation

I have what I feel is a good foundation to a bugs simulator, but I am not getting the animation movement that I desire.

**What is the best approach when working with canvas to create a move fluid movement in animations**.

I am new to javascript and just messing around so any recommendations to improve on my coding standards are welcome as well.

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/UmSss/11/

HTML

```
<canvas width="578" height="200"  margin="3px" id="targer" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('targer');

  function bugObj(x, y, size) { 
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        this.update = function(move) {
            var p = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)-1) + this.x;
            var q = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)-1) + this.y;
            if (p > canvas.width) { p = canvas.width };
            if (p < 0)   { p = 0 };
            if (q > canvas.height) { q = canvas.height };
            if (q < 0)   { q = 0 };

            this.x = p;
            this.y = q;
        }
        return this;
    }

    function popBugs(){
        var bug;                
        var ctv = canvas.getContext('2d');  
        ctv.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctv.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for(var i = 0; bug = bugs[i]; i++) {                
            ctv.fillStyle = 'yellow';
            ctv.fillRect (bug.x, bug.y, bug.size, bug.size);                
        }

    }

    var bugs = [],
        numberbugs = 100,
        x,y;

    for (var i = 0; i < numberbugs; i++){
        x = Math.random()*canvas.width;
        y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height);
        bugs.push(new bugObj(x, y, 2)); 
    }

    function loop() {

        /// update each bugs objects
        for(var i = 0;i < bugs.length; i++) bugs[i].update();           

        popBugs();

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    loop();

    window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
              function( callback ){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000);
              };
    })();
```

Comment: i have no idea what you are asking,what you are trying to do?

Comment: Asking for suggestions to increase the fluidity of the moving "bugs"

Comment: you want them to move more swiftly

Comment: I not sure I can do swiftly http://jsfiddle.net/UmSss/12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things to try to make the animation smoother:

1. Make the movements smaller.
2. Don't black out all the bugs at one time and then redraw them. Black out each bug and immediately redraw it in yellow. Do each bug in turn.
3. Keep track of which way a bug moved last time and only allow it to move that direction or 90 degrees to either side.
4. Set up the bugs in 10 groups of 10 and have a timer for each group. This keeps the bug motion from being synchronized with the other bugs and may look better to the eye.

Comment: I like your answer better than mine.

Comment: @Tyler The speed thing is a great idea. Assign each bug a speed (deltax, deltay) along with the position. Then vary the speed by a small random amount. Then move the bug according to the new speed.

Comment: I think I will try this out thanks for the suggestion, I changed my code to keep track of the old bug cords and draw over them individually right before the new bug spot is drawn. Now for the rest of the changes

Comment: This one is a little different. It uses the speed thing. http://jsfiddle.net/UmSss/19/

Comment: This one doesn't blank the whole screen at once but erases each bug right before redrawing it. http://jsfiddle.net/UmSss/20/

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing what you're trying to do here is to make the bugs fly smoothly from one location to the next instead of just shaking like they are now.

There are a million different ways to do it, but here is what I would do to get the ball rolling. Again this is a start, just to start using destinations rather than random frame by frame movement.

1. The first time you call update on any of the bug objects I would generate a random DESTINATION.
2. Each time you call the update function after that, you move the bug towards that location. To make it better, assign each bug a random SPEED, or investigate certain types of easing functions (ie. In each frame, finding the half way point between the bug and its destination and moving it there will create an easing effect.)
3. Each time you call the update function, you'll also check to see if the bug has reached it's destination. If it has, then create a new random destination and send the bug on it's way, otherwise just keep the bug moving along it's path.

This would be just a start, later you would want to get into the use of velocities/vectors, and some basic trig so when a bug turns towards a new destination the path is a small arch rather than a sharp turn.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the bugs are moving a random number of pixels every frame. That gives them a jittery effect. If you want them to look more like they're crawling, you need to have them always moving forward but turning randomly. For that, you'll need a more complicated algorithm. For starters, you'll need to have velocity for each bug that changes the position on each frame and work with changing that velocity over time.

You may also want to investigate [Steering Behavior](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/) which is probably more like what you're looking for.